# How to prove this natural deduction?

Tags: logic, proof, proof-of-correctness

I'm trying to prove this formula but its really hard..
Here is the formula:

```
¬∃x.(P(x)∧R(x)) Premisse
¬∃x.(S(x)∧¬R(x)) Premisse
∀x.(A(x)→P(x)) Premisse

∀x.(A(x)→S(x)) Conclusion
```

I'm actual in this step:

[image: http://puu.sh/lvPhf/a3545ecc32.png]

Any one knows how to proceed?

Comment: Don't premise 1 and 2 contradict each other? 1 says ¬∃x.R(x) and 2 says ¬∃x.¬R(x).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assume `A(x)` is `true`.
- By Premise 3 `P(x)` must be `true`.
- By Premise 1 `R(x)` must be `false` (otherwise, `P(x)` and `R(x)` would be both `true`)
- By Premise 2 `S(x)` must be `false` (otherwise, `S(x)` and `¬R(x)` would be both `true`)
- Therefore `¬S(x)` is `true`

So, `A(x) → ¬S(x)` and given that `x` was arbitrarily chosen:

```
∀x.(A(x) → ¬S(x))
```

and the conclusion you were given is wrong.